# Wso2 backchannel logout url giving Unauthorized

Tags: wso2, logout, wso2-identity-server

I am sending to **https://localhost:9443/backlogout?logout_token= my_id_token** and getting unauthorized.

Comment: What is the hostname of the IS server and your service provider? From this, I could understand that your application is running on the localhost domain. Can you elaborate your question with those details and add the screenshot of the service provider configurations?

Comment: Are you trying with OIDC back-channel logout or OIDC RP initiated logout? Why id token hint is used in back-channel logout?

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect URL may be a cause for 401 unauthorized response.WSO2 IS doesn't have an endpoint as `/backlogout`.
Refer to [1](https://medium.com/@piraveenaparalogarajah/configuring-openid-connect-back-channel-logout-using-wso2-identity-server-8c758310525f), [2](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-openid-connect-back-channel-logout/#configuring-openid-connect-back-channel-logout_1) guides for Configuring OpenID Connect Back-Channel Logout using WSO2 Identity Server.

Comment: so i set it in my serviceProvider Oauth2 configuration backChannelLogoutUrl,under enabling backChannelLogout box

Comment: It should be the service provider's back-channel logout endpoint URL to which the logout token is sent to. It is not an endpoint of IS. see guide 2 I have linked.

Comment: getting the same result with sending post request **https://localhost:9443/SERVICE_PROVIDER_NAME/backlogout?logout_token=idtoken**

Comment: Is your service provider is running in port 9443 of a host named localhost, and the service provider's back-channel logout endpoint is /SERVICE_PROVIDER_NAME/backlogout ?

Comment: Exactly. I have done by this example,[1](https://medium.com/@ashend/openid-connect-backchannel-logout-144a3198d2a) , and sending post request, and still getting unauthorized. Also i don't have **events** claim in my **idToken**.

Comment: are there ways of invalidating user session in wso2 from my backend (like in keycloak using refreshToken)?